# Positioning views within the AppCompat toolbar in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to place a RelativeLayout within a Toolbar so that I can position views easily within the Toolbar. This Toolbar is used in standalone mode and has two menu items.
I have this in my layout xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:background="#ff17182b">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f76865"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFD10202"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:text="Stopped"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7DCi.png is a link to a screenshot of the resulting UI

With the layout above, the RelativeLayout is positioned to the left and its right border stops just at the left border of the toolbar menu items. it is as if the menu items cover the area from the top of the screen to the end of the toolbar and won't allow placing of elements within that area

Please, I need to know if I am doing anything wrong or if there is a right way of positioning views within a toolbar

Comment: Have you come right yet? I am currently working on the same stuff and I may have some help for you.

Comment: No, I didn't figure it out but I used another layout instead but please do share your solution